# Scrollview vs Collectionview. Get "visible image"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode9

**What I want to achieve:** I have an array of images that I want to horizontally swipe/scroll through. These images represent contacts. When I find the contact(image) I want, I press a separate Start Call button. This button segues to a Phone view controller. I need to display an image of the person I'm calling on that Phone view controller. To do this I need to know what contact image I was on before I initiated the segue.

[My contacts view controller. Currently showing my scrollview attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZkdL.png)

**What I currently have:** I have a scrollview and a separate collectionview already set up (they are in NO WAY connected to each other. I have both because I'm trying to figure out which gets me what I need). Both are fully functional and allow me to page through images from my array. 
I can’t figure out how to pragmatically get which image is being displayed when I press the button that would initiate the segue to the next view controller.

I was originally trying to tag the images and then retrieve the tag and pass it to the next view controller via segue. 
I then tried to get the index of the image that is "currently visible" and pass it via segue.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ImageCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell

    cell.imgImage.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]

    //Get character for segue
    selectedCharacter = indexPath.row

    return cell
}
```

I also tried to get the image name and pass that via segue.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ImageCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell
    switch cell.imgImage.image{
        case UIImage(named: "Van"):
            selectedCharacter = 2
        case UIImage(named: "Fel"):
            selectedCharacter = 3
        default:
            selectedCharacter = 1
    }
}
```

I have yet to be able to figure out any way to get info with the scrollview.
Scrollview viewDidLoad code:

```
@IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!


for i in 0..<images.count {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        let x = self.view.frame.size.width * CGFloat(i)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: 0, width: 343, height: 244)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.image = images[i]
        imageView.tag = i

        scrollView.contentSize.width = scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(i + 1)
        scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
    }
```

**The Question:** Does anyone have any ideas on how I get which contact I'm trying to call and if I should use a scroll view or a collection view?

Thank you!

Comment: Show some code. What have you tried? What isn't working specifically? Your question is too broad for anyone to be helpful at this point.

Comment: @skladek Alright. Made some edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where you click, but you can get the current view index with this:
     let index = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.bounds.size.width
collectionView or scrollview is the same

Comment: This worked! I used the collectionView with `let indexHolder = Int(collectionViewer.contentOffset.x/collectionViewer.bounds.size.width)` and I was able to pass the indexHolder when I pressed my separate call button to the next view controller

Answer (score 0):

you can use a collection view. create a custom cell class that has an `image` property. when you are about to return the cell in the `cellForItem` function, you can set the `image` property.

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Your Cell's identifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)
cell.image = imageArray[indexPath.item]
```

you can then override the `didSelectItem`, and access the `image` property of the cell at the `indexPath` that is passed in like so:

```
let cell = collectionView!.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
let image = cell.image
// do whatever you need with the image.
```